# Coldfusion 11 MVC and pretty URL

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, pretty-urls

I'm currently creating a website using my personal MVC architecture. Doing the edits on Coldfusion Builder 2016, which I believe that by default, my website is running on Tomcat Server.

I have 3 separate folders for the MVC : `model`, `view`, `controller`.

And in the `view` folder, I have a sub folder named `rooms`, and inside them was `create.cfm`, `edit.cfm`, `list.cfm`, and `view.cfm`, each for its own purposes.

I've tried adding mappings to my `application.cfc`, but I can't understand how that things worked. As far as I know, `.htaccess mod_rewrite` will not be read by the tomcat server.

As an example, I want my website to load proper files just from the URL. `E.g: http://localhost:8500/spr/rooms/list.cfm`. `rooms` being was a representation of the scope of its module. Other applicable modules includes `.../spr/users/*.cfm` and `.../userRoles/*.cfm`.

I've also put a bunch of `cflog` on the `onError` and `onMissingTemplate` inside `application.cfc` to check which function executed if I go to `http://localhost:8500/spr/rooms` to handle it via redirects and `cfinclude template="..."` options. Sadly, only the Apache Tomcat HTTP status 404 pops up, and even the logs over at `onRequestStarted` inside my `application.cfc` wasn't even executed.

Is there any other ways around this? I don't want to move the views to another folders just for the sake of naming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you saving by writing your own MVC framework? This has been solved many times over by established frameworks.  If you want rewrites in Tomcat, use Tuckey.  Or better yet, use CommandBox to start your servers (disclosure, I'm the lead dev) as it does rewrites out of the box.

Comment: I was new to the language, so I guess doing some simple projects was the best way to learn was to write some codes.

It was for an upcoming project that I'll be assigned to. It's good to know CFC can work as both model and controller.

Comment: +1 for what Brad said. (I've met Brad at a CF convention, he's an awesome dude and I put a lot of weight into his advice). We use ColdBox for our MVC. FW/1 (Framework One) is another popular option. Both are super easy to get up and running. Using an established framework saves you time, and the authors are familiar with and have incorporated security best practices. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This was a dummy project for the real one (the management are still working on the requirements) so I wanted to learn a bit more about CFML. I'll probably use the framework suggested for the real deal. Again, thank you.